# May I use 1V 5A load to 24V 3A rating relay?

Tags: relay

Can I relay 1V 5A(5W) load to 24V 3A (72W) rating relay?

[image: photo from >>https://protosupplies.com/product/hrs1h-s-dc5v-3a-relay/]

Comment: What's the nature of your load?  Is it a motor?  An incandescent bulb?  A purely resistive load?

Answer (score 7):

For reliable operation - NO.  In this application the current rating of the relay (what the contacts can carry) is more important than the voltage rating.  So to carry 5 amps, you want a relay rated at least 5 A DC (I assume this a DC application).  And for long term reliability you want to derate the relay by at least 50 %, so that means looking for a 10 A relay.

All that said, if this is for breadboard application where the relay might only switch a handful of times, you might be able to get away with using the 3 A relay here.

Comment: Be aware that too _low_ a current _also_ has an effect on the lifetime of the relay. You want a Goldilocks relay, not just a "large enough" one. Good datasheets give minimum switching current.

Comment: True.  But the level of currents that require special contact material is much, much lower than the 5 A OP needs to switch.

Answer (score 4):

Since the contact rating is the same (3 A) at 250 V AC, 120 V AC and 24 V DC it is clear that the relay is intended for resistive loads only.

It also implies that the contact rating of 3 A resistive cannot be exceeded at any voltage.